# Angular JS - ng grid tab out issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, ng-grid

First consider a grid of width 400px, which has four columns. All columns are of width 100px. Tabbing between columns works as expected.

```
.gridStyle {
    border: 1px solid rgb(212,212,212);
    width: 400px; 
    height: 300px
}
```

[Plunk 1](http://plnkr.co/edit/whE0iGAti6eNYdwrY9A6?p=preview)

Now a similar kind of grid with the same 400px width, again with four columns. But this time each column has 300px width. Now tabbing between columns does not work. It is tabbing out only within the columns which are visible on the screen.

```
$scope.columns = [
    {  
      "field": 'Classification',
      displayName: 'Classification',
      width: '300 px',
      cellTemplate: link
    },
    {
      "field": 'name',
      displayName: 'Name',
      width: '300 px'
    },
    {
      "field": 'age',
      displayName: 'Age',
      width: '300 px'
    },
    {
      "field": 'Classification',
      displayName: 'Classification',
      width: '300 px',
      cellTemplate: link
    }
];
```

[Plunk 2](http://plnkr.co/edit/tBaxljQpzcIZoN2mf7rS?p=preview)

See the two Plunks to compare behaviour.

I am not sure why this is happening. I am displaying almost 20 columns in the ng-grid, and would like to implement the functionality to tab between columns. But can't. Can someone help me on this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I've been having exactly this same issue, and it's been driving me up the wall. I came here hoping to find an answer, but no luck.

So after much research, it seems to me that this is just a bug in ng-grid. There seems to be no way to resolve it... except to upgrade to the renamed new version of ng-grid, ui-grid.

It looks fairly straightforward, and all the common gotchas in upgrading are documented [here](http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/tutorial/099_upgrading_from_2).

I've forked and updated the second Plunk from your question ([Plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/FXynrweDKfYWN2HFeP9Y?p=preview)), and while it doesn't quite look perfect, it's a good proof of concept.

In a nutshell, change the module dependency from `ngGrid` to `ui.grid` plus any additional features you need:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp',
    ['ui.grid', 'ui.grid.cellNav', 'ui.grid.edit', 'ui.grid.selection']);
```

...and add these same dependencies as directives on the same element as `ui-grid="gridOptions"`:

```
<div class="gridStyle"
    ui-grid="gridOptions"
    ui-grid-cellNav
    ui-grid-edit
    ui-grid-selection>
</div>
```

You can see in the Plunk that tabbing beyond the edge of the viewport *just works* in ui-grid (with `ui-grid-cellNav`), no hacky workaround required.